# how to get data from start date to end date?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a column store date in mysql database.I need to get data from 2013/5/10 to 2013/12/10. I know how to extract data between them but not starting from 2013/5/10 to 2013/12/10. 
How to get data between these dates ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: whats your column datatype?

Comment: Possible Duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

You can select records from 2013/5/10 and upto 2013/12/10 like below.

```
SELECT * from TableName WHERE DateColum >= '2013-5-10' AND DateColumn <= '2013-12-10';
```

or

```
SELECT *  FROM  TableName WHERE DateColum BETWEEN  '2013-5-10' AND  '2013-12-10'
```

Comment: thanks balajimca. i did same but it retrieves data between '2013-5-10' AND '2013-12-10